How can i convert a blob image into a byte array?
I have a blob (image) like this: blob:http://localhost:3000/3c2fca6b-74fa-44d0-b6f0-d4ea451005ec
How can i turn this into a byte array?
I need to save this to my database
I tried doing this:
async function blobToByteArray(blobUrl: string) {
  const response = await fetch(blobUrl);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  return byteArray
}

but i get errors saying that the fetch is invalid and that i cannot cast to string failed for value "Promise {///}
Thank you so much for everyone that will help im seriously going crazy!!

How did you get the blob? Also, for database sanity you generally don't want to save the image itself in your database, you want to save the file to a file system (e.g. a static asset folder, an S3 bucket, what have you) and then save the image metadata along with the location the file lives at in your DB, instead.


i cannot cast to string failed for value Promise {///}

This likely happens because you call your method blobToByteArray without awaiting it. Async functions return promises. Try calling it with await: await blobToByteArray(...).
